# how to convert dataAndTimePicker value to a string in c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, visual-studio

I need help, I am trying to write a query string that gets data according to a particular date picked in the *dataAndTimePicker tool* but I keep getting the same exception **"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."**
this is the code I tried

```
str = "select imId,imCustomer,imAmount,imDiscount,imTotal,imPaid,imPayType,imDate from invoiceMaster where imDate >= '" + startDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "' and imDate <= '" + endDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(str, declerations.con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dgvInvoice.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) to learn how you could do it the way you're asking for as well as why you should not and what you should do instead, which is much as the answer below suggests.

Comment: Are you sure your dates are stored as strings in the database?

Answer (score 2):

Always use parameters instead of putting a values directly into a sql string

```
 str = "select imId,imCustomer,imAmount,imDiscount,imTotal,imPaid,imPayType,imDate from invoiceMaster where imDate >= @StartDate and imDate <= @EndDate";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, declarations.con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", startDate.Value);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", endDate.Value);
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dgvInvoice.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: still getting an exception "must declare scalar variable"

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "select imId,imCustomer,imAmount,imDiscount,imTotal,imPaid,imPayType,imDate from invoiceMaster where imDate >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(startDate.Value) + "' and imDate <= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(endDate.Value) + "'";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(str, declerations.con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dgvInvoice.DataSource = dt;
```